# How to add new property (index) to each object in array with mapping of knockout (ko.utils)?

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, indexof, knockout-mapping-plugin

Does is any utility for add the index of each object in array as a property in knockout js?
I'm doing that in two steps, I want to add the index property for each object at the same time that is pushed to the array. Here is my code.

```
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(array,
        ko.mapping.fromJS(result)());

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   array[i].index = i;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why do you put index into your array elements?

Comment: Not sure why you would want the index as a property. Does it need to update if you amend the array?

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of not answering your question:

If you loop through an array in a foreach: binding, you will have an observable $index available for you to reference the index in the array.

If you made your array an observableArray, you could attach a computedObservable to your model that performs soemthing like:

```
myArray()[i].index = ko.pureComputed(()=>myArray().indexOf(myArray()[i]))
```

I believe that index will be a observable that will notify subscribers when the array is changed (and hence the index needs to be recalculated).